# How to take care of the battery when on AC power?

Tags: battery

I've recently bought a new notebook. I would like to hear your advices/tips on taking care about its life. I will use the notebook on AC power. What should i do with the battery in that case (to last longer), should i keep it plugged (after it reaches 100%) or i should unplug it and let it on a desk to "rest" while it's draining to ~30 then again charge fully? thanks.

The battery is : **6Cells 4700 mAh 50 Whrs**